# Given an svc file/wsdl, how to create the service in Visual Studio/c#

Tags: wsdl, service-reference, svc

I do have the service and a service reference. Problem is that this service is a part of a legacy, monolith solution - and I really do not want to touch it.

What I would like is a new (fake) service providing me with reliable test data during development and manual testing.

Is there a way to create a new service with the same footprint as specified in the svc-file or wsdl?